# How do I iterate over rows and return a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm afraid this might not be the right way of doing this, so any other ideas are welcome. But I have a function that takes a `DataFrame` to do some calculation. However, now I need to iterate over another `DataFrame` rows and pass a that row to that function, but as a 1-tuple `DataFrame`:

I've tried:

```
for u in df.iterrows():
   foo(u)
```

But foo is a tuple... I can do several steps and convert to DataFrame (maybe), but is there a clean (or better way than) iterating over rows and returning a 1-line dataframe?

Comment: a more concise way is `df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(foo), axis=1)`. However, my general advise is to revise `foo` so that it can be vectorized.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.apply(lambda x: foo(pd.Series(x)), axis=1)` or, depending on Your function, something like  `df.apply(lambda x: foo(pd.DataFrame(x).T), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':110}, {'A':12,'B':120}])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    tpl = tuple([row['A'], row['B']])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much more efficient to use apply function than iterating through the rows of a dataframe.

Assuming that df is your dataframe, you can write this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: foo(pd.DataFrame(x)), axis=1)
```